# Uber Sandbox Api request scope

Tags: uber-api

I am currently making a Simple Application that helps to book uber cabs. I need to test the ride request feature, hence I am using Sandbox API. However, as my app is not yet ready for production I cannot have the request scope. Whenever I send a request call to the Sandbox API all I get is this error

{
"message": "Missing scope: request",
"code": "unauthorized"
}

How do I get the access to make test calls? My app is not yet ready for production to apply for real API. Please Help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create ride requests in your app, you still need to authorize the application with the `request` scope. However, you will be granted with limited access unless you specifically request the full access, as outlined in the [Developer Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard):
[image]

In other words, the app you created will not create real ride requests until you are approved for the full access. Therefore, you can extend your OAuth scopes and include `request`. After that, issue a [`POST /v1/requests`](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests). You will now have a mocked ride request and you can apply the [sandbox methods (e.g. PUT)](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/sandbox) using the mock `request_id`.

Comment: So, can I have a mock ride request with Limited Access?

Comment: Correct, limited access does not book real rides.

Comment: Cool, Thanks, a mock ride request is all I need.

Comment: I'm requesting for 3 scopes while log in. .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS,Scope.REQUEST)) 

But It's showing an Authentication error "CONNECTIVITY_ISSUE" after approving the permissions. Any idea?

Comment: have some contact in uber that is possible to request these scopes?